# nav2_planner not working

Tags: ros, ros2, frames

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am correctly running rviz2, nav2_map_server and correctly visualizing the map. I want now to use a nav2_planner to see the path built. However it happens that when I run the node and activate it publish reapeatedly this:

```
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist. canTransform returned after 1.00296 timeout was 1.
Warning: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
         at line 133 in /home/jenkins-agent/workspace/ci_packaging_linux/ws/src/ros2/geometry2/tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

Here the terminals where i run the nav2_util and nav2_planner:

Terminal 1:

```
lorenzoteo@lorenzoteo-HP-ZBook-15v-G5:~$ ros2 run nav2_util lifecycle_bringup nav2_planner
```

Terminal 2:

```
lorenzoteo@lorenzoteo-HP-ZBook-15v-G5:~$ ros2 run nav2_planner planner_server
[INFO] [nav2_planner]: Creating
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Creating Costmap
[INFO] [nav2_planner]: Configuring
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Configuring
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Subscribing to the map topic (/map) with transient local durability
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "static_layer"
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Subscribed to Topics: 
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "obstacle_layer"
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initializing inflation layer!
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Initialized plugin "inflation_layer"
[INFO] [nav2_planner]: Created global planner plugin GridBased of type nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner
[INFO] [nav2_planner]: Configuring plugin GridBased of type NavfnPlanner
[INFO] [nav2_planner]: Activating
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Activating
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Checking transform
Warning: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
         at line 133 in /home/jenkins-agent/workspace/ci_packaging_linux/ws/src/ros2/geometry2/tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp
[INFO] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: StaticLayer: Resizing costmap to 1006 X 689 at 0.200000 m/pix
Warning: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
         at line 133 in /home/jenkins-agent/workspace/ci_packaging_linux/ws/src/ros2/geometry2/tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343800/nav2_planner-not-working/) by [lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/51527/lorenzo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2020-02-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-02-11**:
Did you give a starting pose estimate for there to be a complete TF tree?

**Comment by [lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/51527/lorenzo/) on 2020-02-12**:
What do you mean exactly? I run these two following nodes for tf transforms:

ros2 run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 world map

ros2 run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 10 10 0 0 0 0 map base_link

Not enough?

Edit: I want to give the starting pose estimate through rviz.

**Comment by [Clionadh](https://answers.ros.org/users/52408/clionadh/) on 2020-05-22**:
Did you fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes. I do not remind what is exactly the problem, but you need to set use_sim_time to false if you do not have gazebo running and the tf tree must be complete: map->odom->base_link.

---

Originally posted by [lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/51527/lorenzo/) with karma: 88 on 2020-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0